# Slipstream additional programs into XP installation disc?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, automated-install, windows

I am trying to work out if it's possible to add additional programs to the default Windows XP disc. I am using nlite and it seems to work well for hotfixes etc. but not for specfic programs.

The main programs I am trying to get added are:

- AniTa Emulator (http://www.april.se/english/anita.asp)
- Malwarebytes
- Doug Knox Security Center
- CCleaner
- Piriform Defraggler
- BGInfo
- AVG

Has anyone had any luck getting any of the above slipstreamed into an installation? I am aware of a site called ninite.com which can package them all into one executable but I don't know how to add this to the actual install disc.

Thanks in advance!

Danny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ninite is great for the software they have, but useless if you want software they don't currently support.  It's also commercial, you you really need a subscription if you're doing anything with it on a commercial basis.

What you actually want for slipstreaming software in your XP install CD is [Nlite](http://www.nliteos.com) which lets you configure which Windows components are included and configure some of the settings and add additional drivers and software and servicepacks.  There's a load of addons with additional software listed at [winAddons](http://www.winaddons.com/) though check the age of the software since a lot of it is older versions which you probably don't want.

Hope that's enough to get you started.